# Give an example of an inequality with exactly 3 solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am helping a friend try and do their pre-algebra and cannot for the life of me figure this out. I'm pretty sure it's an error in the phrasing, but I'm not too sure. The only inequalities I can come up with have infinite solutions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: the inequality $x^2\le 0$ has exactly one solution.

Comment: In general you can make up any equation $\ldots = 0$ with exactly three solutions and square it to get an inequality with exactly three solutions as $$(\ldots)^2 \le 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)^2\leq0{}{}{}{}{}{}$.